# Touch screen double tap directly jumps to next to next screen

Tags: c++, qt, touch

I am developing Qt application (Qt version 4.7.3) on SBC6000x board. I am using tslib for touchscreen.

I have 2 screens with 2 buttons at same location. When a button on 1st screen is clicked(touched) it goes to 2nd screen. If I double tap button on 1st screen, it registers 2 touch events. With first touch it goes to 2nd screen and second touch is handled on 2nd screen and 3rd screen is displayed.

So with double tap on 1st screen I directly jump to 3rd screen. I want to prohibit this 2nd touch.

Here are the things I tried out.

1. I looked for changing debounce time in tslib but could not get enough information.
2. Disable buttons on 2nd screen, enable them when screen gets loaded.

**Problem with 2nd approach**:
   I not creating screens at runtime, I have an array of screens. If I enable buttons in show() method, I have to disable them somewhere. In what method I should disable them ?

*While showing 2nd screen, I am not calling close() or hide() on 1st screen, I am calling only show() to 2nd screen. So I cannot disable buttons in closeEvent or hideEvent() (As I don't have these methods at all*)

How do I handle this? any help is welcome.

Comment: Make it clear what screen number the user is on and provide a back button?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [work with Qt's Event system](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/eventsandfilters.html). It'll allow you to track for whatever events are occurring (such as a tap) and override the default behaviour for your custom behaviour. It's pretty wide ranging so it's hard to give you a lot of information, but it's likely you need to look at how it's dealing with button clicks from mouse events as there's no touch specific ones.

Comment: I tried to override event() function. On paint event and hide event I tried logic mentioned in 2nd approach. (As paint is the last thing took place in screen loading). But in even that 2nd touch is registered and acted upon. May be, technically UI is loaded but not visible to user(because of slow refresh rate, display buffer issues etc.) hence 2nd touch is served.

Answer (score 0):

When a button is clicked, instead of calling `myScreen->show()` call a custom method, for example `myScreen->showWithDelayedButton()` which does something along the lines of:

```
MyScreen::showWithDelayedButton() {
    myButton->hide();
    QTimer::singleShot(250, myButton, SLOT(show));
    show();
}
```